# How does a necessary being fully explain contingent beings?

Tags: epistemology, theology, atheism

X contingent <=> there is W s.t. W -> S, where "->" is derivation, not material implication

X necessary <=> X not contingent

Theists claim, without further clarification, that a necessary object X "grounds" contingent Ys, that it provides their "substance of being".

Is that not merely restating that a necessary X delivers axioms that hold for contingent Ys?

But axioms are hereditary, if X fulfills axiom A, and Y follows from X, then Y fulfills A, because one either adjoins independent axioms and leaves A fixed, or applies transformation formulae that contain A and neither violate it nor become independent of it.

So what ever properties the necessary being would have would be conserved in the contingent beings.

Then again, contingent beings are classified by them arising as a state change.

How does a fixed, globally holding necessity, encoding axioms, derive for various contingent things various ways they can be derived?

A necessity is indepenedent of a contingency, as A and NOT A can not have a dependent axiomatization, as you'd derive one from the other in that case.

Comment: Theists and many of their opponents do not think of the relation between necessary God and contingent world on the model of derivation from axioms. The latter is neither necessary nor sufficient for explanation, so axiomatic analysis is not very helpful. For what is involved there see [SEP, Metaphysical Explanation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/metaphysical-explanation/).